# How to camel-case where consecutive words have numbers?

Tags: naming, coding-style

Just wondering if anybody has a good convention to follow in this corner-corner-corner case.  I really use Java but figured the C# folks might have some good insight too.

Say I am trying to name a class where two consecutive words in the class name are numeric (note that the same question could asked about identifier names).  Can't get a great example, but think of something like "IEEE 802 16 bit value".

Combining consecutive acronyms is doable if you accept classnames such as `HttpUrlConnection`.  But it seriously makes me throw up a little to think of naming the class `IEEE80216BitValue`.  If I had to pick, I'd say that's even worse than `IEEE802_16BitValue` which looks like a bad mistake.  For small numbers, I'd consider `IEEE802SixteenBitValue` but that doesn't scale that well.

Anyone out there have a convention?  Seems like Microsoft's naming guidelines are the only ones that describe acronym naming in enough detail to get the job done, but nobody has addressed numbers in classnames.

Comment: Probably not on topic on SO, still an interesting question.

Comment: I'd probably go with `_` if necessary. Everything else I can think of (except reordering where possible) is even worse. In your example `Ieee802Value16Bit` is what I'd do in your example.

Comment: Oops.  I figured with the existence of a naming-conventions tag, it was close enough to on-topic to at least ask. :)

Comment: Simple: do not use camel case. Today there is no reason for it because linkers are not restricted to 6 characters in external names. *I eschew embedded capital letters in names; to my prose-oriented eyes, they are too awkward to read comfortably. They jangle like bad typography.* - Rob Pike, "Notes on Programming in C"

Comment: @Kaz We're talking about C#/Java here. Also beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Personally I think `_` is uglier than camelCase or PascalCase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd figure out a new variable name instead of trying to figure out what naming convention to use for a double-number variable

That said, if I absolutely HAD to use a double-number in my variable name, and I couldn't rearrange the words/numbers to come up with something reasonable, and absolutely no other name would make sense, I would use an `_` between the numbers

...

Actually I take it back, I would just figure out a new variable name :)

Comment: +1 We make network equipment at work, so one would think standard-related class names come up a lot, but I don't remember having this issue, so I looked through our code base.  Instead of prefixes like IEEE802, we use esoteric words like "Ethernet" :-)

Comment: What about `SHA-512/256` or `SHA3-256`? I'm having a hard time coming up with names that don't contain an `_`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd personally go for the underscore route e.g. `IEEE_802_16_BitValue`.  Currently dealing with modelling some CPU architectures, this Q was good timing :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have used some letter to delimit consecutive numbers. For me it would be `Ieee802x16bit` (*not* `IEEE802x16bit`). I think it is less distracting then a lone underbar in the middle of a jungle of letters and digits.